# Create hive table using regex or json SerDe when root is an array

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-serde

My data is in this format

`[{"field1":"data1","field2":100,"field3":"more data1","field4":123.001}]`

`[{"field1":"data2","field2":200,"field3":"more data2","field4":123.002}]`

`[{"field1":"data3","field2":300,"field3":"more data3","field4":123.003}]`

`[{"field1":"data4","field2":400,"field3":"more data4","field4":123.004}]`

(each line is an array with only one object) and I want to create a hive table around this.

If there was no `[]` around the json then I could have easily used default json serde `ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'`.

The problem with regex serde is the order of the fields which can change and is really hard to extract exact values.

How can I create a hive table with such data format?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an `ARRAY<STRUCT`

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-ComplexTypes

I would only suggest using regex if there is always one  JSON object in each row